# Execute JavaScript from MD - Programmatically created page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, gatsby

Is it possible to execute JavaScript in a MarkdownRemark programmatically created page from .md?

I'd like to embed a photogallery from EmbedSocial which requires having a  with a classname and a  tag right under it.

Here it is in the .md file:

```
<div class='embedsocial-album' data-ref="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv123456789"></div>
<script>(function (d, s, id) { var js; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; } js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "https://embedsocial.com/embedscript/ei.js"; d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); }(document, "script", "EmbedSocialScript"));
</script>
```

And here it is on my template file, taking in the GraphQL Query Results:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
```

but I realized, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` doesn't execute the JavaScript found in MD.

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [gatsby-remark-embed-snippet](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-embed-snippet/) for this use case. Then you could include the gallery with e.g. `` `embed:embedsocial.js` `` and put your code in a file called `embedsocial.js` that is a part of your codebase.

Being able to include JavaScript right into the page from Markdown sounds like a security risk (anyone with control over the Markdown can inject code into your site); having a pre-defined snippet is a lot safer.

Furthermore, if EmbedSocial changes its API in the future you can update all instances of the gallery in a single place.

Comment: Where would `\`embed:embedsocial.js\`` be placed?

Comment: That would be the markdown code that embeds the widget.

Answer (score 0):

taking @ehrencrona 's input about the security risk (completely forgot about it), I looked into embedsocial's script which actually just added a  tag to the head of the HTML. Using react-helmet I added the script tag but only for the template page and not the overall application.